# Interfaz en Android

Tags: android, android-fragment, recyclerview

Hace poco tiempo que estoy desarrollando en Android y consultando varios tutoriales no termino de ver una solución a mi problema.
Resulta que necesito una interfaz con varias tabs, cosa que se podría hacer con un `TabLayout` y sus `Fragments`, pero cada `Fragment` tendría un contenido distinto, he visto varios tutoriales pero en la mayoría de ellos lo relaciona con un `RecyclerView` así se puede hacer scroll (cosa que no me dejaba en ninguno de ellos).

¿Alguna idea?

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/coordinator_main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

Comment: La guía de estilo de Material Design de Google el apartado patrones de navegación te puede servir para determinar cual es el mejor para tu app, tabs o tabs  inferiores https://material.io/guidelines/patterns/navigation.html#navigation-patterns

Comment: Muchas gracias compañero, voy a ello

Comment: Ambos los deberías armar con viewpager y fragments, cuando llegue al trabajo mirare de subirte un ejemplo que tengo. El recyclerview es más para mostrar agrupación de listas vertical, horizontal o ambas, pero para contenadores de diferentes pantallas de tu app mejor usar fragments con viewpager

Comment: Exacto eso es lo que he podido consultar en algunos tutoriales, siempre te ofrecen implementar RecyclerView, que quizás sí que me venga bien para alguna Tab ya que el contenido puede ser parecido a un ListView, pero sin embargo en otras Tabs el contenido será totalmente distinto por tanto no sabría que hacer ahí.

Comment: la view que quieras que tenga scroll vertical añadelo dentro  NeestedScroollView,el recyclerview es para mostrar tipo de datos repetitivos

Comment: Gracias Webserveis, ¿pero te refieres dentro del layout del Fragment o en el layout del Main Activity?

Comment: individualmente a cada vista el layout que cargas en la vista mediante fragment, ya que debe ser independiente